# PHP Prepared Statements function

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I want to create a "general" function to deal with all my prepared statements in PHP.

I.e., I want a function like

```
function doStmt($sqlQuery,$types,$arg1,...,$argN) {
    (...)
    if(!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlQuery)) //error blah blah;
    if (!$stmt->bind_param($types, $arg1,...,$argN)) //error ...;
    if (!$stmt->execute()) //error ...;
    $stmt->close();
    return true;
}
```

My problem has to do mainly with how to dynamically set the N arguments to the `doStmt` function and then how to pass them to `bind_param`.

The reason why I want such function is so that I don't need to check for errors & close everytime I use a prepared statement.

Comment: bind_param takes two parameters. Instead make an array and then use it `like $stmt->execute($array)`

Comment: I am guessing you are using prepared statements simply for protection against injection? If your using them for the speed improvement you won't get it with this method. (you may even see a small penalty)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
function doStmt() {
  // You could use func_num_args() get how many arguments do you have...
  $argList = func_get_args();
  $sqlQuery = array_shift($argList);
  $types = array_shift($argList);

  // echo $sqlQuery;
  // echo $types;
  // print_r($argList);

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlQuery);
  call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $argList);
}

doStmt('select ... ? ... ? ... ? ...', 'sss', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3');
```